# Html2canvas screenshot is used but the screenshot is very different from the original

Tags: vue.js, html2canvas

Html2canvas screenshot is very different from the original picture. How to solve it

This is the address of my code  https://github.com/cxm1308377432/html2canvas-screenshot

[The above is the interface written with vue-grid-layout, you can modify the layout at will, and the below is the screenshot, but the two are very different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrzj1.png)

```
function download() { 
  var this1 = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    html2canvas(this1.$refs.mine, { backgroundColor: null }).then(canvas =>   
    { 
         let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         this1.downImg = dataURL; console.log(dataURL); 
    });
  }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: Post most important part of code here if you wanna help from community. Best way is to post code snippet.

Comment: this is about screenshot function  download() {
      var this1 = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        html2canvas(this1.$refs.mine, {
          backgroundColor: null
        }).then(canvas => {
          let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          this1.downImg = dataURL;
          console.log(dataURL);
        });
      }, 1000);
    }    https://github.com/cxm1308377432/html2canvas-screenshot/blob/master/src/assets/img/screenshot.png

Comment: You can download the sample watch, in the local address is https://github.com/cxm1308377432/html2canvas-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You better have a screenshot to show how different it is. But from my experience when I'm working with that library (html2canvas), the canvas can't render from difference origin. That's CORS problem. Unlucky, I haven't found any solution for this situation.
I read your source but can't found any image url so please update your answer with screenshot.

Comment: The original layout can be literally change, click the screenshot button can capture, in the pictures below show, rendering the address https://github.com/cxm1308377432/html2canvas-screenshot/blob/master/src/assets/img/screenshot.png